# Why my IP is not set?

Tags: networking, backtrack

In Backtrack I entered this command :

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

And then set these lines :

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Saved and exited, then restarted my OS. But when I enter `ifconfig` command, it shows me that the:

```
inet addr :192.168.1.105
```

Why ?

I am sure that the previous `vi` command is saved because when I again enter command:

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

the result shows me that:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Don't start any network manager at boot process.

Answer (score 0):

In my debian11 version,the NetworkManager will conflict with Connman.I find that Connman is much better than NetworkManager,please have a try.